# How to use GCC with Conan & CMake on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, cmake, conan

I am tryting to setup a build of a project on my Macbook which should use GCC with both  **Conan** & **CMake**.

I have set the following environment variables:

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-12
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-12
```

When I run **Conan** all libraries are installed (and built if missing):

```
conan install ../ --build=missing
```

My `.conan/profiles/default` shows that **Conan** has used **gcc-12**.

```
[settings]
os=Macos
os_build=Macos
arch=armv8
arch_build=armv8
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=12
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

When I run **CMake** with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc-12 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++-12 ../
```

I get the following error

```
cmake ../
-- Ubuntu: Using Conan to manage dependencies
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: 
~/some-dir/build
CMake Error at build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:1812 (message):
  Incorrect 'apple-clang', is not the one detected by CMake: 'GNU'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:1369 (conan_check_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:62 (conan_basic_setup)
```

`build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:1369` contains the following:

```
message(FATAL_ERROR "Incorrect '${CONAN_COMPILER}', is not the one 
    detected by CMake: '${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}'")
```

This indicates that **CMake** has detected the **Conan** compiler as **AppleClang** NOT **GCC**

I cannot see where **conanbuildinfo.cmake** gets the value for `CONAN_COMPILER` from.
How can I force **CMake** & **Conan** to use **GCC-12**?

Comment: Did you run `conan install ..` command? If yes, did you check which profile was showed? Could you please share that output command? Also could please update your description with your CMakeLists.txt content? It's not clear how you are calling conan and the content of your `conanfile.txt`